# How to position whole page's scrollbar on the left hand side?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, scrollbar, right-to-left

I know it's possible to position a `div`'s scrollbar on the left-hand side by simply using `direction:rtl`, but why the same doesn't work for the whole page?

I tried putting the same rule for both `html` and `body` but no chance and the main scrollbar still on the right.

(I know there are some hacky ways like putting a fixed `div` with `height and width = 100%` and `direction:rtl` that scrolls instead of main page, but isn't there any way to solve the problem directly?)

Answer (score -1):

Set every elements' direction from left to right (`ltr`) except for body (direction: `rtl`)

```css
* {
  direction: ltr;
}

body {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

**Example**:

```css
* {
  direction: ltr;
}

div {
  padding: 5rem;
}

body {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: But setting `direction: rtl` for `body` doesn't affect the main scrollbar's position

Comment: Hi @RezaNooralizadeh, what do you mean? Don't you want the scrollbar of the whole page to be on the left of the site?

Comment: @geekly-quentin No I want it exactly on the left!